# How to disable scrolling in OSMdroid

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I use OSMdroid of the version 3.0.10 in my project. And I want to disable scrolling on MapView. I tried:

```
setFocusable(false)
setEnabled(false)
setClickable(false)
```

methods of MapView with no results. Is there any way to disable scrolling the map?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest solution is to subclass `MapView` and override `scrollTo()`. Instead of calling `super.scrollTo(x,y)` with the x and y parameters that were passed in, call it with the scroll values you want the maps permanently locked to.